# Maven maven-exec-plugin execution before zip packaging

Tags: eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho, exec-maven-plugin

I'm building a Maven+Tycho Eclipse RCP application and I would like to run my codesign maven-exec-plugin on OS X before the product is being compressed to zip and before the binary gets compressed for distribution in repository/binary.

So I suppose that the step should be somewhere between the compiling and packaging but I'm having a hard time just by trial and error. 
Which lifecycle build phase should it be tied to?

My maven-exec-plugin looks like this at the moment (the app gets codesigned but after the zip has already been created):

```
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
            <id>exec</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>codesign</executable>
                  <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>-s</argument>
                    <argument>"My Developer ID"</argument>
                    <argument>-vvv</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/products/${product-id}/macosx/cocoa/x86/MyApp/MyApp.app"</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the prepare-package lifecylce phase in your execution block instead of the package lifecycle phase.

Comment: I just tried but it fails as the MyApp.app file does not exist yet